# ArgumentOutOfRangeException parameter name: Index

Tags: c#, linq

I keep getting this 'ArgumentOutOfRange exception non-negative number required, Parameter name: index', whenever I try to open the page and I can't seem to figure out where/how exactly the negative number is appearing.  Thank you all in advance!!

```
var months = data.OrderBy(x => x.ApproximatedStartDate).Select(x => x.Month).Distinct((x, y) => x == y).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
var upcomingMonths = months.GetRange(months.IndexOf(DateTime.Today.Month), months.Count - months.IndexOf(DateTime.Today.Month));
```

I'm getting the exception when the code reads the 'upcomingMonths' variable.

stack trace:

```
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Non-negative number required. Parameter name: index]
System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource) +72
System.Collections.Generic.List`1.GetRange(Int32 index, Int32 count) +4951591
InitializeChartBC() 
Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +103
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3811
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace.

Comment: What happens if months is empty?

Comment: Why not "Where( Month >= DateTime.Today.Month)" (pseudocode) ?

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful here. It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, or what data you have.

Comment: Well the exception tells you that it is the "index" argument. The stack trace shows that it is the GetRange method of List. Given you only use this once in your quoted code then you can conclude that `months.IndexOf(DateTime.Today.Month)` must be returning a negative number. The documentation of `IndexOf` will tell you exactly when that will return a negative number. Job done. Learning to read exception information is a vital skill while programming and one you should definitely take the time to learn.

Answer (score 3):

According to Documentation header of the List

```
// Exceptions:
//   T:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
//     index is less than 0.-or-count is less than 0.
```

So I think **months** doesn't contain Current Month.
Before you call the months.**GetRange** check whether it contains **current month** and then call the **GetRange**.

```
var months = data.OrderBy(x => x.ApproximatedStartDate).Select(x => x.Month).Distinct((x, y) => x == y).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
 //Anyone corrent me as the list is converted to **.ToList** it wont throw null error I feel
List<T> upcomingMonths = null;  //Where T is the type of the list
if(months.IndexOf(DateTime.Today.Month)>=0)
      upcomingMonths = months.GetRange(months.IndexOf(DateTime.Today.Month), months.Count - months.IndexOf(DateTime.Today.Month));
```

Comment: Bingo! That's the same conclusion I reached.

Comment: If it doesn't contain current month, how exactly would I add that into it before calling GetRange?

Comment: What about using a "Where" instead of "GetRange"?

Comment: Thank you for the example!  I'm not too familiar with checking indexes just yet, how would you go about checking if the index is a negative number, like you said? @john

Comment: @Fildor he wants the list starting at index from where the month starts until the end of the list. If the Data is started then he can check **month** at-least or at-most using where condition

Comment: @Anthony the **if** condition checks for valid index

Comment: @Anthony In C# when an item isn't found, the index returned is -1. Rudresha's code takes care of this by checking the index is >= 0, so it's fine :)

Comment: @john No it's not. What if index *is* -1 ? upcomingMonths will remain null.

Comment: @john yup you are correct he can use the where condition :-) thanks for pointing out

Comment: Ohh I see what you're saying, that makes sense.  I don't know why I never thought of using an IF statement, but thank you Thank you!  I'll try out your suggestions and see if they work :)

Comment: @Anthony I suggest you do `upcomingMonths = months.Where( x => x >= DateTime.Today.Month );` Since `months` is already distinct and ordered, this will give you what you are trying to achieve without having to check for indexes. If there is no "upcoming" month, the list will just be empty.

Comment: Like adding `upcomingMonths = months.Where( x => x >= DateTime.Today.Month );` before the `var upcomingMonths`? Or just replacing it with the where condition?

Comment: That seemed to work, however I have a variable after that, that is similar: `var previousMonths = months.GetRange(0, months.IndexOf(DateTime.Today.Month));` where I get the same exception except the parameter name is Count.

Comment: Oh actually replacing both variables `var upcomingMonths` & `var previousMonths` to `months.Where(x => x >= DateTime.Today.Month);` worked and the page now loads. Awesome, Thank you all!